# How does Github maintain https despite allowing images to be displayed through Markdown?

Tags: ssl, github, https, markdown

As far as I can tell, if the image is non-ssl/http, they download it and self host it.

I ask because I've been working with Markdown recently and read that Stackoverflow is not ssl for reasons related to this.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I can tell, if the image is non-ssl/http, they download it and self host it.

Exactly. For example, see line number three of [this README](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/master/README.md) which contains:

```
![Gitter](https://badges.gitter.im/Join%20Chat.svg)
```

But the rendered [HTML on GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/README.md) contains.

```
<img src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/da2edb525cde1455a622c58c0effc3a90b9a181c/68747470733a2f2f6261646765732e6769747465722e696d2f4a6f696e253230436861742e737667"
  alt="Gitter"
  data-canonical-src="https://badges.gitter.im/Join%20Chat.svg" 
  style="max-width:100%;">
```